# Multiple search terms with awk column search command

Tags: awk

In an `awk` command like below, which searches the second column for the keyword `mouse`, how may I add another search term to perform a search such as "`mouse` **and** `keyboard`" or "`mouse` **or** `keyboard`"?

I want to avoid performing multiple commands.

```
awk -F'\t' '$2~/mouse/' allcombined.txt
```

Comment: Not really specific to either linux or bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add an **and** condition, use `&&` here:

```
awk -F'\t' '$2~/mouse/ && $3 ~ /keyboard/' allcombined.txt
                       ^
                        \---
```

(where I've arbitrarily chosen to require field 3 to match "keyboard".

To add an **or** condition, use `||`:

```
awk  -F'\t' '$2~/mouse/ || $2 ~ /keyboard/' allcombined.txt
```

(here, field 2 can match "mouse" or "keyboard").

You'll need to use parenthesis once your logic extends beyond three elements:

```
awk  -F'\t' '($2~/mouse/ || $2 ~ /keyboard/) && $4 ~ /CIO/' allcombined.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `awk` code, make the test say

```
$2 ~ /mouse/ || $2 ~ /keyboard/
```

or change `||` to `&&` for "and".

Note that this would do regular expression matches (`/mouse/` would match the string `a mouse called Henry`). To make an exact string comparison, use e.g. `$2 == "mouse"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk  -F'\t' '$2~/(mouse|keyboard)/ &amp;&amp; $3~/(x|y)/'
```